# Receiving membership fee payment and recurring contribution in one go

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, recurring-contributions

I am building our new website with CiviCRM, and I would really like to for new members to be able to set up annual membership fee payments (e.g. €15 per year) and recurring contributions (e.g. €30) in one go, instead of having to go through two separate paypal payments.

Both the membership and the donation payments are going to be recurring payments.

Can you give me any advice on how to do this? I can't get it to say anything else than this:

[image: civi-image]

where it says that the money is charged every month, even though I have set the €15 membership fee to not recur automatically, and to be an annual fee.

Or is it necessary to do things serially: First membership fee payment, then setting up recurring donations?

Comment: Just wanted to clarify the membership fee is a one off payment and only the donation element should recur?

Comment: Thank you for helping to improve the question, i've updated it to make it more clear: Both the membership and the donation payments are going to be recurring payments

Comment: Are they recurring on difference frequencies?

Comment: @Parvez Saleh: Ideally, we would like for them to be able to recur at different frequencies i.e. membership fees once a year, and recurring contributions once a month.

Comment: I dont think thats possible unless a plan allows it at the recurring payment processor side. To the best of my knowledge its not possible in CiviCRM without some tweaking.